# passing arguments to dwr call function in javascript with a callback

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, callback, dwr

I have a DWR bean class which i can reference through JavaScript. I also have a function called getWritableContactSQL in that class as

```
public static string getWritableContactSQL(String, String, String){...}
```

Now I have the 3 parameters available to be in the JavaScript code. I want to call this function with those parameters and want to use the output of this function into another JavaScript function as :

```
function slqDone(data){...}
```

If the getWritableContactSQL function did not have any arguments, I would have called it like:

```
getWritableContactSQL(sqlDone);
```

But I have arguments and don't know how to do this. I have practically no knowledge of AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First from the javascript function , java method getWritableContactSQL(a,b,c) will be called.

```
    DwrUtil.getWritableContactSQL(a,b,c,getWritableContactCallBack);

    getWritableContactCallBack is the callback function.
```

After the request is done some data will be returned.This will be  returned in the callback function.

```
    function getWritableContactCallBack(data)
    {
       dwr.util.setValue("divId", "got data", {
                          escapeHtml : false
                        });
    }
```

Comment: hi srikanth i am not able to understand the second function's implementation. can i use my sqlDone function with its current implementation or do i have to modify it accoring to your implementation?

Comment: Modify according to my implementation.In the second function only data  is returned from java method can be used according to requirement.

Comment: can u explain about what i have to do with the second one, do i need to use the dwr.util.setValue()? if yes then is this fine? `dwr.util.setValue("sqltext",data,{escapeHtml:false});`

Comment: dwr.util.setValue() is used to put the data in say sqltext div .Its similar to document.getElementById("sqltext").innerHTML=data

Comment: yeah i got that but i wanted to ask if there is some convention like "got data" in dwr :). very silly of me :S. thanks a lot dude!

Comment: but i think this means that i dont need to modify my implementation of sqlDone.

Comment: "got data" there is no convention like this in DWR.Just for explanation kept it.So your problem solved.